# MYSQL using AS or other variable to query columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

Running into an issue when querying a live variable.

Sorry for the noob question, but why is this failing? I've tried several variants, etc. as shown. Where am I going wrong?

```
SET DAYNAME(CURDATE()) = DAY
IF (DAY = 'Monday')
SELECT ID FROM table WHEN Monday = '1';
```

and

```
SELECT DAYNAME(CURDATE()) AS Day
WHEN Day = 'Monday'
FROM table WHEN Monday = '1';
```

Comment: this is not sql and lacks semi-colons

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results.  Do you have multiple columns (Monday-Sunday) and depending on that day name you want to filter on that column?

Comment: I have a monday column with either 0 or 1 in the field. I want to return only results with 1 in the monday column if it is currently monday.

as far as it being sql, SELECT ID, Monday, Value FROM table WHERE Monday = '1'; pulls only the 1's, and has semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> I have a monday column with either 0 or 1 in the field. I want to
>   return only results with 1 in the monday column if it is currently
>   monday.

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
select * 
from yourtable
where monday = 1 and DAYNAME(CURDATE()) = 'Monday'
```

Comment: sgeddes, thank you so much. I've been running my head into a wall for the past 4 hours. (and a couple of days mentally). i owe you a beer.